# Is there any difference in these prepared statements using PHP and MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare ("INSERT INTO accounts (type, username, gender, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$q -> bind_param('sssss', ($_POST['type']), ($_POST['username']), ($_POST['gender']), ($_POST['email']), ($_POST['password']));

$q -> execute();
```

Compared to;

```
$type = $_POST['type'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$q = $dbc -> prepare ("INSERT INTO accounts (type, username, gender, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$q -> bind_param('sssss', $type, $username, $gender, $email, $password);

$q -> execute();
```

Are there any benefits of doing it either way?

Thanks.

Comment: I moved your variable declarations to occur before the statement, otherwise all the variables would be empty, and I doubt you wanted that. Switch it back if for some reason you DID want that.

Comment: @eykanal: You should not make any correction to the question you can format but you should not correct the code. Think about the answer of @paragon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're both the same, which is better just depends on which you find easier to read and maintain really.

Comment: Ye, I think the first is better less code, and better loading times! Was just making sure they were the same :p

Comment: Agree with Basic - The first one doesn't generate the local variable clutter and is much more readable. PHP developers tend to assign post and get variables to local variables.. I don't see a point on doing that knowing it will spawn noise into the code...

Answer (score 3):

No, these techniques are both identical.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between these two statements (as far as I can tell) is that you're grabbing the POST variables ahead of time in the second example.  This accomplishes nothing unless you need those variables later, or you simply want your code to make a little more sense.